# Are there better alternatives to g.drawString() / g2D.drawString()? (solved)

Tags: java, text, render, draw, paint

I have been trying to put text onto an already existing window for a while now.
I want to be able to add, remove, arrange and rearrange paragraphs across the screen.

At first I tried to add text components - which had a delay of several seconds.
Next I experimented with geometry in the paint component of JPanel-derivate, was delighted at how everything appeared instantly, and fell for a delusion that text would behave the same. But when I tried the drawString() method, I was met with a similar delay as before.
Maybe this is a problem with my computer specifically and doesn't happen elsewhere.
I would still like to remedy it though.

Eventually I wrote this monstrosity:

```
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Schrift arabic = new Schrift(1368, 680, new Letter[] {
        new Letter('0', new int[][][] {{{361, 1385, 134, 1385, 52, 1145, 52, 915}, {52, 915, 52, 702, 134, 443, 361, 443}, {361, 443}, {363, 443, 588, 443, 669, 689, 669, 914}, {669, 914, 669, 1126, 588, 1385, 361, 1385}}}, new int [][][] {{{363, 1334, 236, 1334, 197, 1113, 197, 912}, {197, 912, 197, 710, 230, 494, 360, 494}, {360, 494}, {361, 494, 489, 494, 524, 707, 524, 912}, {524, 912, 524, 1116, 491, 1334, 363, 1334}}}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('1', new int[][][] {{{580, 1368, 162, 1368}, {162, 1368, 162, 1326}, {162, 1326, 294, 1317, 303, 1302, 303, 1196}, {303, 1196, 303, 644}, {303, 644, 303, 568, 297, 561, 235, 557}, {235, 557, 157, 554}, {157, 554, 157, 519}, {157, 519, 225, 503, 347, 475, 437, 443}, {437, 443, 437, 1196}, {437, 1196, 437, 1302, 447, 1317, 580, 1326}, {580, 1326, 580, 1368}}}, new int[][][] {}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('2', new int[][][] {{{612, 1368, 48, 1368}, {48, 1368, 48, 1333}, {48, 1333, 130, 1253, 216, 1171, 288, 1087}, {288, 1087, 380, 981, 472, 863, 472, 739}, {472, 739, 472, 619, 408, 548, 300, 548}, {300, 548, 198, 548, 135, 627, 95, 686}, {95, 686, 60, 654}, {60, 654, 149, 530}, {149, 530, 197, 481, 267, 443, 352, 443}, {352, 443, 488, 443, 607, 538, 607, 692}, {607, 692, 607, 817, 552, 900, 409, 1045}, {409, 1045, 204, 1251}, {204, 1251, 475, 1251}, {475, 1251, 558, 1251, 575, 1247, 622, 1152}, {622, 1152, 666, 1166}, {666, 1166, 645, 1233, 629, 1302, 612, 1368}}}, new int[][][] {}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('3', new int[][][] {{{248, 1385, 178, 1385, 115, 1355, 93, 1334}, {93, 1334, 71, 1316, 66, 1298, 68, 1279}, {68, 1279, 70, 1260, 90, 1238, 105, 1228}, {105, 1228, 117, 1218, 130, 1218, 143, 1228}, {143, 1228, 179, 1260, 245, 1308, 331, 1308}, {331, 1308, 431, 1308, 503, 1233, 503, 1090}, {503, 1090, 503, 956, 399, 903, 316, 903}, {316, 903, 283, 903, 246, 911, 223, 918}, {223, 918, 214, 874}, {214, 874, 347, 832, 446, 777, 446, 672}, {446, 672, 446, 581, 383, 536, 306, 536}, {306, 536, 224, 536, 165, 596, 127, 653}, {127, 653, 95, 622}, {95, 622, 162, 528}, {162, 528, 204, 481, 272, 443, 354, 443}, {354, 443, 355, 443}, {355, 443, 492, 443, 580, 526, 580, 637}, {580, 637, 580, 678, 565, 710, 536, 739}, {536, 739, 511, 761, 476, 788, 434, 816}, {434, 816, 434, 819}, {434, 819, 567, 842, 642, 934, 641, 1042}, {641, 1042, 641, 1284, 345, 1385, 248, 1385}}}, new int[][][] {}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('4', new int[][][] {{{673, 1368, 278, 1368}, {278, 1368, 278, 1327}, {278, 1327, 411, 1316, 417, 1304, 417, 1208}, {417, 1208, 417, 1110}, {417, 1110, 29, 1110}, {29, 1110, 29, 1064}, {29, 1064, 178, 851, 328, 643, 479, 447}, {479, 447, 546, 447}, {546, 447, 546, 1037}, {546, 1037, 689, 1037}, {689, 1037, 689, 1110}, {689, 1110, 546, 1110}, {546, 1110, 546, 1209}, {546, 1209, 546, 1307, 554, 1316, 673, 1327}, {673, 1327, 673, 1368}}}, new int[][][] {{{417, 1037, 125, 1037}, {125, 1037, 226, 876, 322, 737, 414, 616}, {414, 616, 417, 616}, {417, 616, 417, 1037}}}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('5', new int[][][] {{{252, 1385, 185, 1385, 122, 1356, 98, 1334}, {98, 1334, 76, 1313, 68, 1301, 71, 1282}, {71, 1282, 71, 1266, 86, 1243, 105, 1228}, {105, 1228, 119, 1218, 131, 1218, 146, 1230}, {146, 1230, 179, 1259, 242, 1310, 335, 1310}, {335, 1310, 456, 1310, 514, 1206, 514, 1100}, {514, 1100, 514, 970, 433, 880, 274, 880}, {274, 880, 210, 880, 153, 898, 118, 909}, {118, 909, 178, 461}, {178, 461, 613, 461}, {613, 461, 622, 472}, {622, 472, 581, 577}, {581, 577, 227, 577}, {227, 577, 188, 839}, {188, 839, 249, 816, 322, 793, 361, 793}, {361, 793, 551, 793, 650, 918, 650, 1039}, {650, 1039, 650, 1128, 607, 1209, 514, 1284}, {514, 1284, 433, 1346, 332, 1385, 252, 1385}}}, new int[][][] {}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('6', new int[][][] {{{366, 1385, 188, 1385, 52, 1244, 52, 1020}, {52, 1020, 52, 701, 281, 536, 441, 481}, {441, 481, 501, 461, 580, 443, 638, 434}, {638, 434, 648, 482}, {648, 482, 600, 491, 540, 509, 487, 533}, {487, 533, 398, 574, 259, 666, 214, 867}, {214, 867, 313, 819}, {313, 819, 347, 804, 376, 794, 405, 794}, {405, 794, 568, 794, 677, 912, 677, 1064}, {677, 1064, 677, 1238, 546, 1385, 366, 1385}}}, new int[][][] {{{390, 1333, 274, 1333, 198, 1193, 198, 1017}, {198, 1017, 198, 983, 200, 943, 207, 916}, {207, 916, 242, 899, 288, 880, 342, 880}, {342, 880, 344, 880}, {344, 880, 473, 880, 539, 995, 539, 1117}, {539, 1117, 539, 1212, 503, 1333, 390, 1333}}}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('7', new int[][][] {{{264, 1369, 146, 1385}, {146, 1385, 135, 1368}, {135, 1368, 296, 1123, 463, 823, 583, 577}, {583, 577, 259, 577}, {259, 577, 160, 577, 150, 590, 112, 686}, {112, 686, 68, 686}, {68, 686, 83, 597, 90, 523, 98, 461}, {98, 461, 677, 461}, {677, 461, 689, 478}, {689, 478, 548, 774, 406, 1069, 264, 1369}}}, new int[][][] {}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('8', new int[][][] {{{357, 1385, 191, 1385, 66, 1294, 66, 1139}, {66, 1139, 66, 1072, 101, 1032, 133, 1002}, {133, 1002, 157, 979, 214, 941, 264, 912}, {264, 912, 169, 860, 102, 788, 102, 685}, {102, 685, 102, 560, 211, 443, 374, 443}, {374, 443, 376, 443}, {376, 443, 519, 443, 622, 541, 622, 660}, {622, 660, 622, 702, 607, 745, 578, 777}, {578, 777, 565, 791, 527, 823, 463, 865}, {463, 865, 568, 924, 660, 992, 660, 1120}, {660, 1120, 660, 1292, 488, 1385, 357, 1385}}}, new int[][][] {{{374, 1336, 373, 1336}, {373, 1336, 283, 1336, 194, 1265, 194, 1129}, {194, 1129, 194, 1049, 242, 978, 309, 935}, {309, 935, 430, 995, 530, 1053, 530, 1161}, {530, 1161, 530, 1270, 460, 1336, 374, 1336}}, {{418, 844, 310, 791, 224, 745, 224, 638}, {224, 638, 224, 565, 274, 493, 357, 493}, {357, 493, 358, 493}, {358, 493, 425, 493, 504, 544, 504, 669}, {504, 669, 504, 755, 465, 807, 418, 844}}}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter('9', new int[][][] {{{93, 1391, 84, 1346}, {84, 1346, 300, 1311, 462, 1161, 510, 948}, {510, 948, 414, 999}, {414, 999, 380, 1017, 352, 1023, 325, 1023}, {325, 1023, 163, 1023, 54, 908, 54, 755}, {54, 755, 54, 615, 168, 443, 364, 443}, {364, 443, 366, 443}, {366, 443, 556, 443, 666, 611, 666, 809}, {666, 809, 666, 1078, 511, 1265, 310, 1345}, {310, 1345, 233, 1374, 135, 1390, 93, 1391}}}, new int[][][] {{{390, 937, 267, 937, 192, 828, 192, 702}, {192, 702, 192, 615, 235, 494, 342, 494}, {342, 494, 344, 494}, {344, 494, 484, 494, 521, 669, 521, 801}, {521, 801, 521, 831, 520, 865, 516, 899}, {516, 899, 487, 919, 440, 937, 390, 937}}}, 722, new int[][] {}),
        new Letter(' ', new int[][][] {}, new int[][][] {}, 400, new int[][] {})});
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        PaintPanel canvas = new PaintPanel();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        canvas.painting = new Area[] {arabic.print(" 0123456789",73.).ink};
        canvas.colours = new Color[] {Color.BLACK};
        canvas.freshup();
    }
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{
    Area[] painting = new Area[] {};
    Color[] colours = new Color[] {};
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2D.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
        int jobs = painting.length;
        int task = 0;
        while (task < jobs)
        {
            g2D.setColor(colours[task]);
            g2D.fill(painting[task]);
            task ++;
        }
    }
    public void freshup() {this.repaint();}
}

class Schrift
{
    int ascent = 0;
    int descent = 0;
    Letter[] symbols = null;
    
    Schrift(int chosenAscent, int chosenDescent, Letter[] chosenSymbols)
    {
        ascent = chosenAscent;
        descent = chosenDescent;
        int cells = 0;
        int sample = 0;
        int fullset = chosenSymbols.length;
        while (sample < fullset)
        {
            int id = (int)(chosenSymbols[sample].name);
            if (id > cells) {cells = id;}
            sample ++;
        }
        cells ++;
        symbols = new Letter[cells];
        sample = 0;
        while (sample < fullset)
        {
            symbols[(int)(chosenSymbols[sample].name)] = chosenSymbols[sample];
            sample ++;
        }
    }
    
    Double measure(String line, Double size)
    {
        Double dimension = 0.;
        int letters = line.length();
        int beispiel = (int)(line.charAt(0));
        int num = 1;
        while (num <= letters)
        {
            if (beispiel < symbols.length)
            {
                Letter zeichen = symbols[beispiel];
                if (zeichen != null) {dimension += Double.valueOf(zeichen.width);}
                if (num < letters)
                {   beispiel = (int)(line.charAt(num));
                    if (zeichen != null && beispiel < zeichen.kerning.length)
                    {dimension += Double.valueOf(zeichen.kerning[beispiel]);}   }
            }
            num ++;
        }
        dimension *= (size / (ascent + descent));
        return dimension;
    }
    
    Schnipsel print(String line, Double size)
    {
        Area ink = new Area();
        Double dimension = 0.;
        AffineTransform placing = new AffineTransform();
        int letters = line.length();
        int beispiel = (int)(line.charAt(0));
        int num = 1;
        while (num <= letters)
        {
            if (beispiel < symbols.length)
            {
                Letter zeichen = symbols[beispiel];
                if (zeichen != null)
                {
                    ink.add(new Area(placing.createTransformedShape(zeichen.form)));
                    dimension += Double.valueOf(zeichen.width);
                    placing.translate(zeichen.width, 0);
                }
                if (num < letters)
                {
                    beispiel = (int)(line.charAt(num));
                    if (zeichen != null && beispiel < zeichen.kerning.length)
                    {
                        Double kern = Double.valueOf(zeichen.kerning[beispiel]);
                        dimension += kern;
                        placing.translate(kern, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
            num ++;     
        }
        AffineTransform shrink = new AffineTransform();
        Double scale = (size / (ascent + descent));
        shrink.scale(scale, scale);
        return new Schnipsel(ascent/scale, descent/scale, dimension/scale, new Area(shrink.createTransformedShape(ink)));
    }
}

class Letter
{
    char name = ' ';
    Area form = null;
    int width = 0;
    int[] kerning = null;
    
    Letter(char chosenName, int[][][] outlines, int[][][] clearings, int chosenWidth, int[][] kerningChoice)
    {
        name = chosenName;
        form = new Area();
        AutoPath painter = new AutoPath();
        int toAdd = outlines.length;
        int spot = 0;
        while (spot < toAdd)
        {
            form.add(new Area(painter.trace(outlines[spot])));
            spot ++;
        }
        int toRemove = clearings.length;
        spot = 0;
        while (spot < toRemove)
        {
            form.subtract(new Area(painter.trace(clearings[spot])));
            spot ++;
        }
        width = chosenWidth;
        int partners = 0;
        int zeichen = 0;
        int fullset = kerningChoice.length;
        while (zeichen < fullset)
        {
            if (kerningChoice[zeichen][0] > partners) {partners = kerningChoice[zeichen][0];}
            zeichen ++;
        }
        partners ++;
        kerning = new int[partners];
        zeichen = 0;
        while (zeichen < fullset)
        {
            kerning[kerningChoice[zeichen][0]] = kerningChoice[zeichen][1];
            zeichen ++;
        }
    }
}

class Schnipsel
{
    Double ascent = null;
    Double descent = null;
    Double width = null;
    Area ink = null;
    
    Schnipsel(Double chosenAscent, Double chosenDescent, Double widthFound, Area shapes)
    {
        ascent = chosenAscent;
        descent = chosenDescent;
        width = widthFound;
        ink = shapes;
    }
}

class AutoPath
{
    GeneralPath trace(int[][] line)
    {
        GeneralPath form = new GeneralPath();
        int arcs = line.length;
        int step = 0;
        while (step < arcs)
        {
            int points = line[step].length / 2;
            if (points == 2)
            {form.append(new Line2D.Float(
                line[step][0],line[step][1] ,
                line[step][2],line[step][3]),true);}
            else if (points == 3)
            {form.append(new QuadCurve2D.Float(
                line[step][0],line[step][1] ,
                line[step][2],line[step][3] ,
                line[step][4],line[step][5]),true);}
            else if (points == 4)
            {form.append(new CubicCurve2D.Float(
                line[step][0],line[step][1] ,
                line[step][2],line[step][3] ,
                line[step][4],line[step][5] ,
                line[step][6],line[step][7]),true);}
            step ++;
        }
        int end = arcs - 1;
        int last = line[end].length - 1;
        if (line[0][0] == line[end][last-1] && line[0][1] == line[end][last]) {form.closePath();}
        return form;
    }
}
```

… which works fine, but has the problem that I will need to transcribe all the geometric information from any font that I would want to use - thus I am not quite sure if I should keep building on it or if that would just be a waste of time.

Update: Under a different Question I found the info that drawString() only needs a few seconds to load the font you are using when you draw your very first words. After that it apparently works (for practical purposes) instantly - I don't know why I never thought to check what would happen with the seconds line of text that I would ask the computer to draw.

Comment: No idea what you are really asking or what your code is doing. But regarding your "revalidate()" question. In general components should be added to the frame before the frame is made visible and the size of the frame should be set before the frame is visible. If you want to change the "painting" or "color" properties of your class, then you should have a setPainting(...) and setColor(...) methods. In those methods you would invoke repaint() to force you component to repaint itself.

Comment: @camickr Thanks a lot - you just gave me all the hints which I needed in order to solve the second problem :)

Comment: @camickr About what my code is doing - it describes areas shaped like the letters of a font and puts them together according to the width information and kerning rules from said font. The only problem is that I have to get all the information from the font into my code before I can use it - and that would be a lot.